# Record place name

Tags: place-name

I’m looking at records and it lists birthplace as Haelfsa Cassel (it is in fancy cursive writing so it is difficult to read).  Could also be Haefsa or Kaefsa/Kaelfsa.  Does anyone know what this is or means?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the birthdate?

Comment: A picture would help, and adding the tag *handwriting* afterwards would prevent the issue to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If the time frame is between 1567 and 1803, the most likely explanation is landgraviate [Wikipedia: Hesse-Cassel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landgraviate_of_Hesse-Kassel), the precursor of federal state called *Hesse* today. In older print fonts *s* and *f* are barely distinguishable, and in script fonts *H* may be misread as two characters.

(I admit, that a whole state is not a very precise specification of a birthplace, but may be the village was too small to be known.)

Comment: Answer is absolutely fine, but: Depending on the time frame, doesn't necessarily need to mean the state of Hessen-Cassel: It could also simply mean "Kassel in Hessen" - Kassel (adopted the "K" in favour of the former "C" in 1926) is a town (city today) in Hessen.